Conformal coating PCBs: dipping vs spraying
I am looking at a proper conformal coating system for my growing company.  I have come across a conformal coating that does not require masking: nanoGuard. On the phone with them, I have asked if they recommend dip coating, and they said no, they recommend selective coating (4-axis).
Their arguments:

Dipped circuit boards can contaminate the coating supply.
Better control of thickness with spraying.
May need a system for automatically topping up solvent to control viscosity.

My counter-arguments:

I can save hours and hours of programming time--zero programming time.
I can coat a dozen or more boards at once.
Huge reduction in complexity.
Boards are cleaned before being coated, so I see contamination being very minimal.
Systems like the Gen3 DC NANO 2002 dip coater (can) come with automatic viscosity control and solvent top-up, so I don't see any problem with this.

In my mind, selective coating has been the go-to method because it saves time masking. Now the medium itself saves time masking, so dipping is surely the way to go. Maybe they have a deal with some seller of selective conformal coating machines. I really need a second opinion.

I tried these "no masking" types, they seem to be on the scam side of things IMO. If it falls off your connectors that easily, then common sense dictates that it will as well fall off the areas you need to protect. Didn't really notice any difference between boards covered in that and boards with no coating at all.

@Lundin did you use actnano or Electrolube? or some other brand? Very curious to hear more about your application and your experience with these.

I don't recall as I weren't involved in the experiment personally, but we never went for the "no mask" version and this would happen at the assembly contractor side. We use Electrolube.

You didn't consider a  third option: brushing (painting).
Having tried both dipping and spraying, we ended up with painting as the most practical solution. Compared to the dipping and spraying:

It allows selective coverage, leaving contact points clear of coating; no need for masking
It uses less material; coat only one side and only the areas that require coating, and there is no wasted material from over-spray
It releases far fewer volatile compound into the environment (compared to spraying)
It deposits a consistent thickness

